# How to make my upvote/downvote button store cookies in database?

Tags: javascript, css, html, cookies

[This](https://fiddle.jshell.net/g6Lhurae/36/) is my upvote/downvote button. Now I want it to store cookies in the database of my website. But I am not familiar with that. Currently I am using a localstorage script which is also buggy and not working.

Note: I know their are lots of way of doing it, but I don't even know a single way. I am newbie at this time.

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">   </script>
<div id="buttons">
<div type="image" class="buttonup" id="plus" style="vertical-align:middle"></div><span id="count">0</span>
<div type="image" class="buttondw" id="minus" style="vertical-align:middle"></div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#buttons{
width: 100%;
height: auto;}
.buttonup {
padding: 0px;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer;
margin-right: 0px;
background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/jWPUjR9.png');
}

 #count {
 display: inline-block;
 border-radius: 0px;
 background-color: #33cc33;
 border: none;
 color: #ffffff;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 18px;
 padding: 7px;
 width: 50px;
 margin-top: 0px;

 }

 .buttondw {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer;
margin-left: 0px;
background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/Vu6tuf9.png');
}

 .buttonup:hover {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/SFjZ9FD.png")
}
 .buttondw:hover {
 background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/aVAeO0F.png")
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var counter = 0, // Try change this what ever you want
 votePlus = counter + 1,
  voteMinus = counter - 1;

function checkIfUserVoted() {
 return localStorage.getItem("voted");
 }
 if (!localStorage.getItem("voted")) {
 localStorage.setItem("voted", counter);
 $("#count").text(counter);
 }
 $(".buttonup").click(function() {
 var vote = checkIfUserVoted() != votePlus ? votePlus : counter;
  localStorage.setItem("voted", vote);
  $(this).next().text(vote);
 });
 $(".buttondw").on('click', function () {
  var vote = checkIfUserVoted() != voteMinus ? voteMinus : counter;
  localStorage.setItem("voted", vote);
  $(this).prev().text(vote);
  });
```

Comment: *"...store cookies in the database of my website"* doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: *"Can someone please edit the javascript for me? I am newbie at this time."* Stack Overflow is not a code editing service. It's absolutely fine to be a newbie. What you need to do is research, reading, experimentation, etc.

Comment: hmm..I just want that counter not to reset everytime  i refresh the page.

Comment: If the votes are meaningful in a way other than just to the user of the browser, the only secure way to do that is to store it on your server, associated with a user ID that's not easily hacked. If the information is just for the user of the browser and not intended for other use, look at [web storage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/).

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code, [Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/3ttqky2k/2/), i try to use the snippet but the `localStorage` is not working. Suggestions only, better if you user server scripting for this functions, because `localStorage` are not good for this functions.

Comment: But it is storing things only in my broswer :/

Comment: yes, because web storage, if you want to save database, use server scripting.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to modify your script to set and get the vote count as below. [Updated Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/g6Lhurae/38/).

**Explaination:**

1. Initialize your counter to 0 or the previously stored value using `if`condition.
2. Display the counter value. This shows 0 or the previously stored value based on storage.
3. On button click **increase** or **decrease** the counter and store the new value in storage.

```js
$(function() {
  var counter = 0;

  if (localStorage.getItem("voted") == null)
    localStorage.setItem("voted", counter);
  else
    counter = localStorage.getItem("voted");

  $("#count").text(counter);

  $(".buttonup").click(function() {
    counter++;
    localStorage.setItem("voted", counter);
    $("#count").text(counter);
  });

  $(".buttondw").on('click', function() {
    counter--;
    localStorage.setItem("voted", counter);
    $("#count").text(counter);
  });
})
```

Comment: I don't want to store them on local browser. The saves vote only in my broswer :(